# Ubuntu 18.04 boot error. Unable to display, GUI isn't working but CLI is

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, live-usb, lenovo

The boot works fine until the pink Ubuntu screen appears for a minute or so and then black screen shows up with some text.

[image]

My problem is that the GUI display isn't opening, but the original TTY CLI is working fine. When I run `xhost` command on it, it says `xhost : unable to display ''''`

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a 16GB Sandisk pendrive as bootable stick on a Windows 7 Lenovo IdeaPad Z560 PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't seem xhost(GUI) thing, but seems more like there is bad sector in boot-sector. this did magic. just, make new bootable-usb of the same ubuntu version.Then, boot up the pc with both the bad pendrive and newly made bootable-usb plugged in.This(bootable-usb) guides you to Install or Savemode.and choose Savemode.Now you see the friendly used-to normal screen of ubuntu.Then use aplication called

```
BOOTREPAIR
```

just double click and run it.This repairs your bad sector of boot-sector in the pendrive.Then shutdown PC.Making sure to plug out newly made bootable-usb and Finaly, plugin the pendrive and boot. that's it!!!